# PDO Error I don't know how to fix

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

## I have this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' in /srv/users/wiput/apps/gallery/public/auth.php:56 Stack trace: #0 /srv/users/wiput/apps/gallery/public/auth.php(56): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /srv/users/wiput/apps/gallery/public/auth.php on line 56

#### in con.inc.php

```
<?
$db_server = "localhost";
$db_user = "gallery";
$db_password = "<censored>";
$db_name = "gallery";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:server=$db_server;Database=$db_name",$db_user,$db_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

#### in auth.php

```
<?
ob_start();
session_start();

//Global Variable
$username = $_REQUEST["username"];
$password = $_REQUEST["password"];
//Convert to MD5
$md5_pw = md5($password);
//Check Blank form
if($username == '')
{
    $_SESSION["error"] = 2;
    header("location:index.php");
}
elseif($password == '')
{
    $_SESSION["error"] = 3;
    header("location:index.php");
}
else
{
    //Connect file
    require("con.inc.php");
    //Check data
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE username= :username AND password= :md5_pw ";
    $result = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $result->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $result->bindValue(':md5_pw', $md5_pw);

    $result->execute();

    $data = $result->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    if ($data !== false)
    {
        echo 'Hi! ', $data['firstname'];
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["error"] = 1;
        header("location:index.php");
    }
}
?>
```

I use serverpilot web server with PHP 5.6.
If any one can please fix it.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, you don't have an active database selected. The reason is that your names in the DSN string is way off. In particular, `Database` should be `dbname` and `server` should be `host` (while the current value works because it defaults to localhost, probably - the dbname is what is giving you the error). Be sure to use the actual format and don't invent your own names.

See [PDO_MYSQL DSN for the correct format](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).

Comment: Could I ask you another help?
> echo 'Hi! ', $data['firstname'];
This line I can't display this data.

Comment: @wiput1999 Please create a new question if you want more answers - the reason here is that fetchAll returns an indexed array - one for each row. Try `$data[0]['firstname']`.

Answer (score 1):

To add more to this, this is because your database could not selected. 
It could be various reasons.
Try this: `$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_server;dbname=$db_name",$db_user,$db_password);` 
rather than `$conn = new PDO("mysql:server=$db_server;Database=$db_name",$db_user,$db_password);` and see if it works as server is suppose to be host, and database is suppose to be dbname. 
I usually connect to the database by doing this $conn ->exec('USE gallery;');